# Stage of new keybinds in 2.8 beta

Tags: shortcut

Honestly i find them very cluncky. Lots of them are missing, e.g. Shift + C.
Will they be re-added or will we have to patch it ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> was returned a few days ago, try last build.

Information about changes in keymap you can find here:  https://developer.blender.org/T55162